# Small-Oh proofs

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to prove $\ o(x^{m+n}) \subseteq o(x^m)*o(x^n) $.

I'd like to prove by definition.

Let $\ f(x) \in o(x^{n+m})$ and $\ h*g=f $

$\ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{m+n}}=0 $

From this we can say:
$\ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{h(x)}{x^{m}}*\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)}{x^{n}}=0 $

From here the conclusion is simple.

My question is, how can I define h and g correctly?

Comment: Begin by writing correctly what you want to prove.

Comment: When you have the limit, you simply write $x^{m+n}$ in the denominator, not $o(x^{m+n})$. Also, I'm not sure that this statement is true. Are you saying that every element in $o(x^{m+n})$ is the sum of an element in $o(x^m)$ and an element in $o(x^n)$? That's definitely not true.